# getenv("HOME") returns null in native code for android

Tags: android, c++, getenv

I am calling getenv("HOME") from a C++ code which is called from an Android app. for IOS getenv("HOME") returns the corresponding directory but for Android it is null. How can I get the directory where I can read and write files in C++ code for Android?

Comment: I guess each app should store its data in one of the places pointed out in [Data and file storage overview](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage).

Comment: Android **doesn't have** a home directory